# What is a Junon Boy?

Tags: barakamon

Kotoishi Naru keeps on calling the main character a Junon Boy. He seems to take this as insulting.

What is a Junon Boy and why does he dislike being called that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Junon is a monthly Japanese fashion magazine primarily directed towards teenage girls and women. It began circulation in June 1973.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junon_%28magazine%29)

Given Junon super boy contest is a beauty contest I would guess, "Junon Boy" basically means "pretty boy".

The magazine hope page can be found at: http://www.junon-boy.jp/

I am basing my answer on research so perhaps some one else can confirm this, also I could not find any information of the meaning of maganize name alone, so again I am basing on the circumstances.

Comment: This is right as far as I can tell.

Comment: The only context I've heard "Junon" used is referencing the magazine or contests, so I'm pretty sure this is correct. It's worth pointing out that the homepage for the contests is http://www.junon-boy.jp/.

Answer (score 0):

Someone replied about Junon Boy on [Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090317184028AA8Jyd9) 5 years ago. Hope this helps a little bit.

> It is a beauty contest for young boys, like teenage boys. Junon is a magazine, like Seventeen. I don't know what they win, but I think many girls' readers vote, and I believe the winner will get some money and a contract with some actor/modeling agency.
>
> Most of the contestants are just young boys who want to be actors/models.

Comment: Answers which are just a link to another site are discouraged, since they can easily go stale or go away.  Summarizing it yourself makes it much more useful.

Comment: Please edit the relevant content into your answer here. As is, this does not answer the question asked, though there might be relevant content in the link.